# After reinstalling linux on the framwork laptop the fingerprint reader in not behaving properly

Tags: linux, fedora, fingerprint

I installed Fedora 35 on the framework laptop and set up fingerprint reader for login and sudo.

The for some reason I formatted the laptop and installed Fedora 35 again. Then strange behavior started: When I wanted to enroll the same finger, it would go well, but before the last step it would error: "Fingerprint device disconnected".

Then I tried enrolling another finger which succeeds, but then on the first usage (login or sudo), it will fail and never suggest to use the fingerprint again.

I guess I need to clean the old enrolled fingerprints from the device, but could not find any resources regarding this.

How should I proceed? Thanks

EDIT: The output of: `systemctl status fprintd`

```
● fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-11-30 09:18:23 PST; 24s ago
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)
   Main PID: 19931 (fprintd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 38206)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 83ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
             └─19931 /usr/libexec/fprintd

Nov 30 09:18:22 fedora.mycompany.com.beta.tailscale.net systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Nov 30 09:18:22 fedora.mycompany.com.beta.tailscale.net fprintd[19931]: Failed to open /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-9/power/persist
Nov 30 09:18:23 fedora.mycompany.com.beta.tailscale.net systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Nov 30 09:18:23 fedora.mycompany.com.beta.tailscale.net fprintd[19931]: libusb: error [udev_hotplug_event] ignoring udev action change
Nov 30 09:18:23 fedora.mycompany.com.beta.tailscale.net fprintd[19931]: libusb: error [udev_hotplug_event] ignoring udev action change
```

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl status fprintd`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs updated the question with the result of that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://community.frame.work/t/fingerprint-scanner-compatibility-with-linux-ubuntu-fedora-etc/1501/88), this python script can clear all enrolled fingerprints:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import gi
gi.require_version('FPrint', '2.0')
from gi.repository import FPrint

ctx = FPrint.Context()

for dev in ctx.get_devices():
    print(dev)
    print(dev.get_driver())
    print(dev.props.device_id);

    dev.open_sync()

    prints = dev.list_prints_sync()
    print("num prints stored: %d" % len(prints))
    for p in prints:
        print('deleting print:')
        date = p.props.enroll_date
        print('    %04d-%02d-%02d valid: %d' % (date.get_year(), date.get_month(), date.get_day(), date.valid()))
        print('    ' + str(p.props.finger))
        print('    ' + str(p.props.username))
        print('    ' + str(p.props.description))

        dev.delete_print_sync(p)

        print('deleted')

    dev.close_sync()
```

I saved it as `clear_fingerprints.py` and ran `sudo python clear_fingerprints.py`, then restarted (just to be cautious) and enrolled my fingerprints again.